# Shrink a vector from N1 down to N2 items without triggering the default constructor and using only move semantics

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl, move-semantics

Could you help me with an efficient way to shrink an `std::vector<T>` from `N1` down to `N2` (`N2 <= N1`) items in it without requiring `T` to have a default constructor (i.e. `resize()` is not an option because it requires a default constructor because it can be used to grow also), and using only move semantics (without requiring a copy constructor/assignment operator in `T`)? Whether the operation actually shrinks the allocated memory is optional (I haven't yet decided which one is better for my program).

What I have tried so far:

```
template<typename T> void Filter(vector<T> &v) {
    // ... Filter the N1 items of the vector and move them to the first N2 positions
    vector<T>(move(v)).swap(v); // this is wrong
}
```

Comment: what about shrink to fit?

Comment: _without requiring a copy constructor/assignment operator in T_ also no move assignment operator?

Comment: @Berto99, move semantics is ok, but copy is not.

Comment: @OznOg, `shrink_to_fit` doesn't reduce the number of items in the vector - it only reduces the capacity of the vector allegedly.

Comment: @SergeRogatch yes I was thinking to erase+shrink_to_fit, I didn't elaborate, but an answer gives it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to do it in-place, maybe just `erase` will be enough:

```
v.erase(v.begin() + N2, v.end());
```

Comment: As long as it has `O(N1)` complexity, this seems to be the best answer.

Answer (score 2):

What about something like this?

```
void foo(std::vector<T>& vec)
{
    const std::size_t n = /* ... */;
    std::vector<T>(
        std::make_move_iterator(std::begin(vec)),
        std::make_move_iterator(std::begin(vec) + n).swap(vec);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simplest solution is to erase the elements:

```
v.erase(v.begin() + N2, v.end());
```

You can reduce the reserved size if desired:

```
v.shrink_to_fit();
```

---

You can also use the other overload of `std::move` to create a new vector containing the subset of elements:

```
std::vector<T> filtered;
filtered.reserve(N2);
std::move(v.begin(), v.begin() + N2, 
          std::back_insert_iterator(filtered));
return filtered;
```

Answer (score 2):

`erase` seems the cleaner:

```
v.erase(v.begin() + N2, v.end());
```

but option with `resize` is to provide a dummy object:

```
auto& dummy = v[0]; // assuming non-empty, else create a new dummy object
v.resize(N2, dummy);
```